# combining undefined lists to one list

Tags: python, pandas, list

I'm scraping a website and the needed output is a list of floats.
when scraping I'm getting back lists of the the floats in str.
after converting them to floats I want to combine them to one list so i can iterate over it and write it to csv.

```
    for statname in data['athletes']:
        l = list(statname['categories'][1]['totals'][10:12])
        ast = (l[0])
        nast = []
        nast.append(ast)
        a = list(nast)
        sas = list(map(float, a))
        print(sas)
```

result:

```
[8.8] [6.3] [6.2] [7.6] [3.0][3.8]
```

needed:

```
[8.8, 6.3, 6.2, 7.6...]
```

Comment: Use `[i[0] for i in sas]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
    sas = []
    for statname in data['athletes']:
        l = list(statname['categories'][1]['totals'][10:12])
        ast = (l[0])
        nast = []
        nast.append(ast)
        a = list(nast)
        sas = sas + list(map(float, a))
        print(sas)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
nast = []
for statname in data['athletes']:
    l = list(statname['categories'][1]['totals'][10:12])[0]
    nast.append(l)
sas = list(map(float, nast))
print(sas)
```